# MongoDB stucks at the start for minutes on Windows

Tags: mongodb, windows, containers, windows-container

##### Details

After starting *mongod.exe* as standalone program (Community, without replication), it freezes right after the start (see logs), sometimes for few seconds, sometimes for minutes, sometimes without any freeze at all. While developing my projects I have to restart it frequently. Most delays are *20 seconds*. While freezing there are no logs from the process and it's impossible to make a connection (because it hasn't start listening on the port and even hasn't discovered db files - see logs). After freezing program works normally without any lags/delays/crashes.

It is freezing specifically on my PC (Windows 10 x64 Pro 22H2), not my colleagues'/friends' PCs. It always freezes in project's Win container (base image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/runtime:4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2019 [0f9b29d3ffaf]), but with smaller delay (5-15 seconds) and this is the main problem, because this container goes to production.

Database has no user/pass, and works without SSL/TLS. Executable usually is started as a child process of .NET Framework 4.6.2 program which does correct output/error redirection. The problem appears with manual starting as well. The binding is always 127.0.0.1 to allow only internal connections.

The pattern seems to be random. I tried empty dbpath, i.e. new db, and existing db - no difference. Admin priveledges don't matter. I tried **v3.4.4** (is used in container, I can't upgrade it to newer) and **v5.0.8** (another project - without container, but the same problem). The port is not the standard one, but is always free, and by changing it nothing changes in behavior. <kbd>Ctrl + C</kbd> can't stop immediately and gives several variants of outputs. `--smallFiles` doesn't help. `--syncdelay 0 --nojournal` doesn't help. `-repair` doesn't help. Changing `--bind_ip` doesn't help. Changing '--dbpath' to other drive doesn't help either. Denying to read/write dbpath also causes initial delay.

Tried to set WiredTiger to following value (doesn't help):

```js
db.adminCommand( { "setParameter": 1, "wiredTigerEngineRuntimeConfig": "eviction=(threads_min=20,threads_max=20),checkpoint=(wait=60),eviction_dirty_trigger=5,eviction_dirty_target=1,eviction_trigger=95,eviction_target=80"})
```

##### My thoughts

I've seen a lot of issues which were solved by setting up WiredTiger correctly, but this delay happens before the program makes first mention of it (see log '1.hjson' - "id":22315), therefore this is probably not case, but I am still open for your suggestions.

The delay happens in the first logs. I've taken a quick look at the mongo source code (I don't know C++ well though), and there are some static core initializers (declared with `MONGO_INITIALIZER`). Their order is random and their context in logs somehow varies between '-' and 'main' values. Maybe there is some non-logged initializer which makes creates this delay...

Any help will be appreciated!

##### Logs

The program usually stucks in these log messages:

```json
{"t":{"$date":"2023-07-25T09:32:53.778+00:00"},"s":"D1", "c":"CONTROL",  "id":22615,   "ctx":"-","msg":"Loading library: {toUtf8String_full_path_c_str}","attr":{"toUtf8String_full_path_c_str":"Schannel.dll"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-07-25T09:32:53.781+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4915701, "ctx":"-","msg":"Initialized wire specification","attr":{"spec":{"incomingExternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"incomingInternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"outgoing":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"isInternalClient":true}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-07-25T09:32:53.783+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-07-25T09:33:57.033+00:00"},"s":"D2", "c":"-",        "id":4777800, "ctx":"main","msg":"Ran initializers","attr":{"nodes":["BeginServerParameterRegistration","idl_2d027c0f06ff60334b8c977697f76a27b3b6872d","RegisterErrorExtraInfoForErrorExtraInfoExample","RegisterErrorExtraInfoForDuplicateKeyErrorInfo","RegisterErrorExtraInfoForResolvedView","RegisterErrorExtraInfoForOptionalErrorExtraInfoExample","..."]}}
```

After, program runs normally without any explicit warning/error.

Full logs with different usecases are available on [GitHub](https://github.com/den4md/mongo-db-slow-startup-error-logs) (some information is changed intentionally).

Comment: Please put all relevant information in the question. Reduce the log level to default. Use `jq` tool to print only warning and error messages, see [Log Messages](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/log-messages/#parsing-structured-log-messages) Nobody here will browse your 12 logfiles in github.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit, thank you for feedback. That's good point. I've added the most important (in my opinion) logs. It's hard for me to decide what is really important and can help to investigate the case.